# SQL trigger compiles correctly but throws error

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a trigger that copies the value from one column ("notubes" into another one ("notubesleft") of the same table when a new row is added. The trigger is compiled correctly but when I insert a new row, it throws an error.

My trigger is:

```
create or replace TRIGGER NOTUBESLEFT_INSERT_TRIGGER    
AFTER INSERT ON SAMPLES FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
update samples
 set notubesleft = (select notubes from samples where sampleid = :new.sampleid);
 END;
```

When I try to commit a new row I get the error:

> One error saving changes to table "APEX_WS_PROMETHEUS"."SAMPLES":
>   Row 10: ORA-04091: table APEX_WS_PROMETHEUS.SAMPLES is mutating,
>   trigger/function may not see it
>   ORA-06512: at "APEX_WS_PROMETHEUS.NOTUBESLEFT_INSERT_TRIGGER", line 2 ORA-04088:
>   error during execution of trigger 'APEX_WS_PROMETHEUS.NOTUBESLEFT_INSERT_TRIGGER'
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

I am asking a new question because I could find solutions on how to structure the PL/SQL code of the trigger, but I can't figure out why it does not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with an after-insert trigger?

Comment: Because I thought I first needed to insert the values in the table, before being able to use them to populate another column. It is my first trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (easily) query the table you're inserting into with a row-level trigger. But you shouldn't be querying the table at all, and shouldn't be using an after-insert trigger to do this. Use a before-insert trigger instead; you can get and set the values from the `:NEW` pseudorecord:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NOTUBESLEFT_INSERT_TRIGGER    
BEFORE INSERT ON SAMPLES FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  :new.notubesleft := :new.notubes;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You encountered mutating table problem. There is a restriction that you cannot query a table which is mutating in a FOR EACH ROW trigger

[Trigger Restrictions on Mutating Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm#g1699708)

> If you must update a mutating table, you can bypass these restrictions
>   by using a temporary table, a PL/SQL table, or a package variable. For
>   example, in place of a single AFTER row trigger that updates the
>   original table, resulting in a mutating table error, you might use two
>   triggers—an AFTER row trigger that updates a temporary table, and an
>   AFTER statement trigger that updates the original table with the
>   values from the temporary table.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am also wondering if the FOR EACH ROW is correct. My goal is to only run the trigger for the new row being inserted. I expect that users will only insert 1 row at a time.